# Reset UsedRange without activating the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am reviewing some code that loops through a large number of worksheets and refreshes data connections in each one. Since the tables can change size by quite a lot when refreshed, it is necessary to reset the used range on each sheet and the current code in place is as follows:

```
sh.Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Sheets(OriginalSheet).Activate
```

Simple question - I know that just running `sh.UsedRange` doesn't work, but is there any other way of resetting the used range without activating the sheet?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use the UsedRange? If they're tables, I would use the DataBodyRange. It will always be updated each time the table is refreshed. Check this out for more info on working with tables: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: `sh.usedrange` should work if `activesheet.usedrange` does.

Comment: @PermaNoob - unfortunately due to the way these files are used, the data actually comes in as a QueryTable, then the connection is broken, then it is converted to an Excel Table with no connection, so there is no option to refresh the table directly.

Comment: @Rory - I have tried `sh.usedrange` and it gives me a compile error (invalid use of property) so, unless I am missing something, no it doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: You need to declare `sh` as `Object` rather than `Worksheet` to fool the compiler. :)

Comment: @BBaxter - If there is only one table per sheet, you can refer to it with the index number(if there's only one per sheet, the index will always be 1) on the sheet. Also, have you considered finding the last row and column yourself?

Comment: @PermaNoob - I don't think that will help with what I am after. I don't want to do anything to the used range, I just want to reset it so the file doesn't think it has 500,000 used rows when it actually has 5.

Comment: @Rory - You should set that as an answer. That's definitely something people would look up. And that way, BBaxter can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

VBA-Excel: Clear data from Excel Sheet(WorkSheet)

For­mat: WorkBook.WorkSheet.Range.Clear

Exam­ples:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Clear
```

Clear data from par­tic­u­lar cell:

```
Dim main­work­Book As Workbook

Set main­work­Book = ActiveWorkbook

mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“A2”).Clear

'Will clear the data from Cell “A2”
```

Clear data from more than one cells:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“A1,C3”).Clear

'Will clear the data from Cell “A1” and “C3”
```

Clear data from range of cells:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“A1:C4”).Clear

'Will clear the data from Range of Cells “A1” to “C4”
```

Clear data from par­tic­u­lar column:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“A:A”).Clear

'Will clear the data from entire col­umn “A”
```

Clear data from par­tic­u­lar row:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“2:2″).Clear

'Will clear the data from entire Row 2.
```

Clear all the Used range of data:

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Clear
```

Clear all data from more than columns

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“A:F”).Clear

'Clear data for Columns from A to F
```

Clear all data from more than rows

```
mainworkBook.Sheets(“MyFirstMacro”).Range(“2:5″).Clear
```

Credit: http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-clear-data-from-excel-sheetworksheet/

Comment: What would be really useful is "Clear all data outside of Used Range"

Comment: @Maxcot copy the used range to a hidden worksheet somewhere else and then clear the whole sheet, reimport that range and delete the other sheet. could you please not downvote something just because it didnt have your specific solution? This helped me when i couldnt find any solutions.

Comment: @Maxcot Cot bolshoe :)

Comment: Did I down vote something? Sorry, that was not my intention and I wasn't aware that I did.

Comment: @Maxcot Apologies for assuming that. Did my comment help you create a solution or do you need something else?